# How to display a percentage of an Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How would you print out a percentage of an array?

For example:

if i had

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,10,15,120,102,10])
```

How would you set a percentage of the array to zero? if I wanted to keep the first 10% of an array as it is and change the remaining 90% of the array to zeros?

Thank you in advance?

Comment: percent of its length?

Comment: The subject talks about displaying a percentage but the body talks about setting a percentage. Does the subject need fixing?

Answer (score 12):

This will give you roughly 90% at the front:

```
x[0:int(len(x)*0.9)]
```

And 90% at the back (by skipping the first 10%):

```
x[int(len(x)*0.1):]
```

So to set the last 90% to zero:

```
x[int(len(x)*0.1):] = 0
```

Comment: You missed the part *and change the remaining 90% of the array to zeros*. Add `x[(len(x)*0.1):] = 0`.

Comment: `x[len(x)*0.1:] = 0` will throws an error: `TypeError: can only assign an iterable`

Comment: @levi: what version of NumPy are you using when you get the error?

Comment: Note that using a non-integer number to index an array is currently deprecated (as of numpy 1.8.0). I guess the forward compatible thing would be to cast the result of `len(x)*0.1` to an `int` first before using it.

Comment: using int() leads to approximation errors, it is better to use round instead.

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero: Rounding is just a different way to look at things.  If I say "Give me 90% of a dozen eggs" should I get 10 eggs, or 11?  There is no right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2,3,1,0,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,10,15,120,102,10])

cut_off = int(0.1*len(x))

print(len(x), cut_off)
for idx in range(cut_off,len(x)):
    x[idx] = 0
```

Comment: In NumPy that's very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [2,3,1,0,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,10,15,120,102,10]
index = 10 * len(x) / 100
x[index:] = [0]*(len(x) - 1 index )
print x
>>> x = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,10,15,120,102,10])
change = round(0.9 * len(x)) # changing 90%
x[-change:] = 0 # change from last value towards beginning of array
print(x)
```

yielding

```
[2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

do this work?

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,10,15,120,102,10])
j=len(x)
k=(j/100)*10
for index in range(k,j):
   x[index]=0
```

Comment: In NumPy that's very inefficient.